# PHP Scripts Stops Without any Errors

Tags: php, apache, directadmin

I've seen a couple of similar questions but mine has an interesting twist!
I'm running a full website on an Apache server, hosted by DirectAdmin.
On some of my pages and for some of my users, the html page stops without any errors.
There is nothing on the error log files either.
But when I add these two lines:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
I see a bunch of notices and warnings (which are present in almost all of the pages) and the page gets loaded completely!
Without those two lines of code, the page stops loading half way through.
I even set both max_execution_time and memory_limit to their respective unlimited values but without error_reporting and display_errors, the page won't fully load.
Is it some restriction from the host?
How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** And also the page is in UTF-8 Encoding (no BOM).

Comment: IMO calling these functions just help the server flush all your generated HTML but still hangs on something that might be ran at the end of your script and which is hanging up forever. Try setting the error reporting from your `php.ini` instead to see if there's any difference. Also check your apache error logs for PHP errors that are not reported

Comment: What kinds of "notices and warnings"?

Comment: "_I see a bunch of notices and warnings_" Have you tried fixing them?

Comment: @MiK Things like "undefined variable" for pages which had been included.

Comment: How do you know the script stopped working?

Comment: @AterLux Because the HTML page doesn't fully load. Stops mid way.

Comment: @MiladFaint are you sure the script is stopped? Not being in a dead loop or something like that?

Comment: @AterLux Yes, I'm absolutely sure.

Comment: Are you sure there is no buffered output which is never flushed or something like that? Just add output to the log file at start and end of the script.